# Do monster respawn in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering if monsters in dungeons or in field respawn after an amount of time? Could be great for loots and XP farming.

Comment: Nice short question. Not sure why you're getting downvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, monsters do not respawn.

If you want more monsters, you can leave the game and re-enter to respawn them.

Answer (score -1):

Monsters do respawn on the ps3 version.  If you clear out one "area"  then go clean out 4 more areas you can come back to the area you started in and the monsters will have repopulated.  I dont think this works on pc but ive done it hundreds of times on the ps3 especially to farm ubers.

An area would be defined best as a level or anywherethat u  enter a portal and the leave through another portal or dungean teleporter.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean out?" Do you have to kill every last monster in an area for it to count?